# Puppeteer can't enter innerText into Grid cell

Tags: node.js, cucumber, puppeteer

This is a cucumber, puppeteer node.js project
In my code below from my world file I am trying to double click on a cell and change the inner text

When I watch the browser the correct cell gets the focus but the cell doesn't change to an edit mode for the innerText to be entered. The code runs with no errors but nothing is changed. In other variations, I was actually able to see the new value on the screen, but a total cell that should have changed didn't change, indicating that the value wasn't actually entered.

You will notice that I'm using a different selector from the double click where I'm trying to write the innerText because the selector changed after the double-click, once the cell got focus.

So my question is - how do I enter innerText into an agGrid cell using puppeteer.

```
   async setCellToThisValue(rowIndex, colIndex, cellValue, wait = 0) {
      await this.page.waitFor(5 * 1000);

      //DOUBLE CLICK
      await this.page.evaluate((rowIndex, colIndex, cellValue,) => {

         var targLink = document.querySelectorAll(`div[row-index="${rowIndex}"]`)[1].childNodes[`${colIndex}`]
         var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
         clickEvent.initEvent('dblclick', true, true);
         targLink.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
      },
         rowIndex,
         colIndex,
         cellValue
      );
      await this.page.waitFor(3 * 1000);
      await this.page.evaluate(() => {
     
         document.getElementsByClassName('ag-cell ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-cell-range-selected ag-cell-range-selected-1 ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-column-hover').innerText = '$101'
      },
         rowIndex,
         colIndex,
         cellValue
      );
     
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that function `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements instead of a single element because mutliple elements can have same class names. Therefore it does not contain field `innerText`.

You need to uniquely identify the element and then set his innerText. You can do something like this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-cell ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-cell-range-selected ag-cell-range-selected-1 ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-column-hover');
if (elements.length !== 1) {
  console.error("Did not select unique element.");
} else {
  var element = elements[0];
  element.innerText = "$101";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.querySelector` to get the first element of the list